# Execute javascript function attached to a html element in python

Tags: javascript, python, dom

What I'm trying to do is what can be done in a browser by running this javascript: `document.getElementById('foo').bar()`.

I don't know how to go about doing this in python. I used to do stuff with submitting forms using twill and sending responses with urllib2, but I never had to do any javascript. Where should I start?

Comment: First you'll need to write a _JavaScript_ interpreter in python or get something like pynarcissus, then perhaps join it to _Beautiful Soup_ so that you can render the page in your new _Python_ web browsing client. Next, fire it up and load your URL. You'll be happy as your interpreter reads through all the `<script>` elements and interprets it. Finally, be sneaky and append your own _HTML_ markup to your generated _DOM_, which includes a custom `<script>` that removes itself and invokes the function you desire.

..Please understand, this is like asking _"How can I make Haskell interpret C#?"_

Comment: @PaulS. right, I just naively thought this would be easier since all I need is to just call that function somehow, I don't even need it's output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are building up your html/js code in the server side and when requested, you will serve that code to the client? As client code will be served you can add it to you logic in the server side:

```
getFooElement = 1;
if getFooElement:
   print "document.getElementById('foo').bar()"
else
   print "HTML/JS code"
```